Redshift returns incorrect results with left outer join
I try to execute this query in AWS Redshift.
with test_1 as (
    select 1 as "a" union select 2 as "a"
),
test_2 as (
    select 1 as "b" union select 3 as "b"
)

select * from test_1 as t1 left outer join test_2 as t2 on t1.a = t2.b; 

I got the result below.



a
b




1
1


2
NULL



The left outer is working as a simple left join.

LEFT JOIN is the same as LEFT OUTER JOIN. (OUTER is optional.)

SQL keywords OUTER and INNER are optional in join operators. LEFT OUTER JOIN <=> LEFT JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN <=> RIGHT JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN <=> FULL JOIN...

"...The left outer is working as a simple left join..." -- Yes, OUTER is an optional keyword.

If I open documentation, I see the following message:
The following query is a left outer join. Left and right outer joins retain values from one of the joined tables when no match is found in the other table. The left and right tables are the first and second tables listed in the syntax. 

Scroll upwards and you'll find the join_type(s).

See example for LEFT and RIGHT (outer) JOINs. And INNER. (https://dbfiddle.uk/O_fsRC4-)
